# How to make copy button copy " not &quot

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a copy button to copy some C++ code and then the user can later paste it into a compiler but when the copy button copies a quotation mark it copies &quot onto the clipboard not the actual mark.

Here's my code:

```
<textarea rows="15" cols=60" id="inputtxt">

  // My c++ stuff  </textarea>  <br>  <button onclick="myfunction();">Copy code</button>
```

and Script:

```
function myfunction() {
var copyTxt = document.getElementsById("InputTxt");
copyTxt.select();
document.execCommand("copy");}
```

How can I make it so it copies the actual quotation mark instead of just &quot?

Comment: There's a couple of issues with that code that means it won't run. But when they're fixed `copy` seems to copy the quotes as is in the demo I ran.

Comment: so what are the issues in the code then?

Comment: You're missing a opening quote in your HTML, and `document.getElementsById("InputTxt")` should be `document.getElementById("inputtxt")`. But you could have looked at the browser log (F12) to work that out.

Comment: Yes actually I just got everything done and it copies fine now. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

`Copy` won't do any encoding or convertings, which means your c++ code is already encoded, so your copied text is entities. Try to look at the source of your html code in your browser rendered to prove it.

If your source code is not entities, then you need to tell us how do you use the copied text, it must be encode at that time.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
        // IE specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
        return clipboardData.setData("Text", text); 

    } else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.textContent = text;
        textarea.style.position = "fixed";  // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in MS Edge.
        document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.select();
        try {
            return document.execCommand("copy");  // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
        } catch (ex) {
            console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
            return false;
        } finally {
            document.body.removeChild(textarea);
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fx6a6n6x/